# setting properties using this keyword in a function

Tags: javascript, html, this

I am practicing `makerjs` with `javascript`.
While I was using, I am having an issue with `this` keyword.

```
//render a model created by a function, using the 'this' keyword

var makerjs = require('makerjs');

function myModel() {

 var line = { 
   type: 'line', 
   origin: [0, 0], 
   end: [50, 50] 
  };

 var circle = { 
   type: 'circle', 
   origin: [0, 0],
   radius: 50
  };

 var pathObject = { myLine: line, myCircle: circle };

//set properties using the "this" keyword ***here I dont' understand
 this.paths = pathObject;
}

//note we are using the "new" operator
var svg = makerjs.exporter.toSVG(new myModel());

document.write(svg);
```

I don't understand how this code works.
After saving with this keyword like bellow,

```
 this.paths = pathObject;
```

How can this works without returning anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myModel` function doesn't need to return anything necessarily, it can also expose properties via `this`. `makerjs.exporter.toSVG` is looking for `paths` property on `new myModel()` instance which you have exposed in the line below.

```
this.paths = pathObject;
```

In the above line you are creating a property `paths` on your current instance, where current instance is accessed via `this`. As you can see in the snippet below i can access `paths` using `m.paths`.

You can read more about how `this` behaves when a function is called as a constructor [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (look for 'As a constructor')

```js
function myModel() {

 var line = { 
   type: 'line', 
   origin: [0, 0], 
   end: [50, 50] 
  };

 var circle = { 
   type: 'circle', 
   origin: [0, 0],
   radius: 50
  };

 var pathObject = { myLine: line, myCircle: circle };

//set properties using the "this" keyword ***here I dont' understand
 this.paths = pathObject;
}

let m = new myModel();

console.log(m.paths)
```

Comment: I totally understood. Thank you very much 